# What is the pushout of $\mathbf{1} \longleftarrow \mathbf{2} \longrightarrow \mathbf{1}$?

Tags: logic, category-theory

I wonder what the pushout of the following diagram would be $$\mathbf{1} \stackrel{f}{\longleftarrow} \mathbf{2} \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf{1}$$(here $\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{2}$ denote the discrete finite category of one and two objects respectively.)

Well, since both $f$ and $g$ can only be the trivial constant function, $f = ! = g$, and my first guess was that the pushout $\mathbf{1}+^{\mathbf{2}}\mathbf{1}$ was $\mathbf{1}$ itself with the identity functor.

But then I realized that this wrong. Because $\mathbf{1}$ is indeed a cocone of the diagram, but not the initial one, for if $Q$ is another cocone with one at least non-trivial morphism, then there is no unique map $\mathbf{1} \to Q$ but many of them.

So what is the pushout of this diagram? Thanks!

Comment: But those other ones will not commute with the maps that define it as a cone, will they?

Comment: Nontrivial morphisms in $Q$ don't give you multiple functors $\mathbf{1}\to Q$, since the only morphism in $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity morphism and functors must preserve identity morphisms.  Rather, there is a functor $\mathbf{1}\to Q$ for each _object_ of $Q$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, $\mathbf{1}$ is the pushout.  Remember that a map $\mathbf{1}\to Q$ to the vertex of another cocone must form a commutative diagram. While there may be many functors $\mathbf{1}\to Q$, only one of them will make the required diagram commute (namely the one that sends the unique object of $\mathbf{1}$ to the object in $Q$ that is in the image of the maps $\mathbf{1}\to Q$ forming the cocone).